# Grails 4 how to get an handle to artifacts in custom command

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I need to build a custom command in a Grails 4 application (https://docs.grails.org/4.0.11/guide/single.html#creatingCustomCommands), and I need to get an handle to some Grails Services and Domain classes which I will query as needed.

The custom command skeleton is quite simple:

```
import grails.dev.commands.*
import org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact

class HelloWorldCommand implements GrailsApplicationCommand {

    boolean handle() {
        return true
    }
}
```

While the documentation says that a custom command has access to the whole application context, I haven't found any examples on how to get an handle of that and start accessing the various application artifacts.

Any hints?

**EDIT:** to add context and clarify the goal of the custom command in order for further recommendation/best practices/etc.: the command reads data from a file in a custom format, persist the data, and writes reports in another custom format.
Will eventually be replaced by a recurrent job, once the data will be available on demand from a third party REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/marco-vittorini-orgeas-artifacts-cli](https://github.com/jeffbrown/marco-vittorini-orgeas-artifacts-cli).

[grails-app/services/marco/vittorini/orgeas/artifacts/cli/GreetingService.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/marco-vittorini-orgeas-artifacts-cli/blob/cf3a3b55679f600af1290540f1e246db9efcf12a/grails-app/services/marco/vittorini/orgeas/artifacts/cli/GreetingService.groovy)

```
package marco.vittorini.orgeas.artifacts.cli

class GreetingService {
    String greeting = 'Hello World'
}
```

[grails-app/commands/marco/vittorini/orgeas/artifacts/cli/HelloCommand.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/marco-vittorini-orgeas-artifacts-cli/blob/cf3a3b55679f600af1290540f1e246db9efcf12a/grails-app/commands/marco/vittorini/orgeas/artifacts/cli/HelloCommand.groovy)

```
package marco.vittorini.orgeas.artifacts.cli


import grails.dev.commands.*

class HelloCommand implements GrailsApplicationCommand {
    GreetingService greetingService
    boolean handle() {

        println greetingService.greeting

        return true
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have added a commit at [github.com/jeffbrown/marco-vittorini-orgeas-artifacts-cli/commit/49a846e3902073f8ea0539fcde550f6d002b9d89](https://github.com/jeffbrown/marco-vittorini-orgeas-artifacts-cli/commit/49a846e3902073f8ea0539fcde550f6d002b9d89) which demonstrates accessing a domain class, which was part of the question I overlooked when writing the initial answer.

Comment: "I haven't found any examples on how to get an handle of that and start accessing the various application artifacts." - @marco-vittorini-orgeas Are there artifacts aside from domain classes and services which you are unsure about how to get a handle of?

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I would like to achieve.To elaborate a bit on the accepted solution, I understand that commands can be injected with services, as in a regular Controller and to persist or custom query/access Domain models the best practice is to write some related Service's method and use that as needed.Is that correct?

Comment: Edited the original question with details of custom command goal.